# Bellman Ford and One Olympiad Questions?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-theory, shortest-path

I took an Olympiad Exam three days ago. I ran into a nice question as follows.

We know the bellman-ford algorithm checks all edges in each step, and for each edge if,

## d(v)>d(u)+w(u,v)

then `d(v)` being updated such that `w(u,v)` is the weight of edge `(u, v)` and `d(u)` is the length of best finding path for vertex `u`. if in one step we have `no update for vertexes`, the algorithms `terminates`. Supposing this algorithm for finding all shortest path from vertex `s` in graph G with `n` vertex after `k < n` iterations is finished, which of the following is correct?

> 1. number of edges in all shortest paths from `s` is at most `k-1`

> 2. weight of all shortest paths from `s` is at most `k-1`

> 3. Graph has no negative cycle.

Who can discuss on these options ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 is incorrect. First of all, we always find shortest paths with k edges, if any. But also, if we happen to relax the arcs in the topological order of a shortest path tree, then we converge in one iteration, despite the fact that the shortest path tree may be arbitrarily deep.

```
s --> t --> u --> v

Relax s->t, t->u, u->v; shortest path from s->v is three hops,
but B--F has made two iterations.
```

2 is incorrect, because who knows what the weights are?

```
  100
s --> t

Relax s->t; weight is 100, but B--F has made two iterations.
```

3 is correct, because by an averaging argument at least one arc of a negative cycle would be unrelaxed. Let `v1, ..., vn` be a cycle. Since the arcs are relaxed, we have `d(vi) + len(vi->vi+1) - d(vi+1) >= 0`. Sum the inequalities for all `i` and telescope the `d` terms to simplify to `sum_i len(vi->vi+1) >= 0`, which says that the cycle is nonnegative.

Comment: very very excellent answer. would you please add more detail. please learn me. an example or a bit more detail. I'm jealous. please waste your valuable time for me.

Comment: Part (1) is indeed true. The idea is that in k steps the algorithm is only considering paths of length k. Indeed, you can prove by induction on k that the path realizing the value of d(v) after k steps is at most k edges long.

Comment: If, however, all edges are evaluated simultaneously ? the first one is incorrect again ? tricky question...

Comment: would you please answer to my comment ?

Comment: I put a bounty please complete it !

Comment: what do you mean by  relaxation simultaneously? any simple example ?

Comment: what do you mean by "telescope the d terms "

Comment: @MaryamGhizhi Write out the sum. Cancel the terms that go, e.g., `-d(v4) + d(v4)`.

Comment: is it possible describe it simpleer?

Comment: @MK Wrong link?

Comment: http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/08-sssp.pdf sorry @DavidEisenstat

Comment: @MK Two different questions here. The p. 295, unoptimized version of Bellman--Ford is the "simultaneous relaxation" version that I'm referring to. Early termination is a different optimization -- since every round of Bellman--Ford does the same operations, if we make no changes for an entire round (for the simultaneous or non-simultaneous version, doesn't matter), then clearly all subsequent rounds won't make changes either, so we can just stop.

Comment: @MK Yes, more precisely, every shortest path found by Bellman--Ford has length at most k where k is the number of rounds completed.

Comment: @MK It's actually just wrong. Off-by-one error. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I'd love challenging question. please see here: I read both of them so my problem when compare two answer 

  https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/40848/bellman-ford-termination-when-there-is-no-change-on-vertex-weights

Comment: @DavidEisenstat any idea here?

Comment: @MK Yuval and I seem to have interpreted the question differently.

Comment: would you please tell me the differences? @DavidEisenstat I love to learn about it.

Comment: please see here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166477/bellman-ford-implementation-and-simultaneously-relaxation

Answer (score 0):

i think option 3 is incorrect because to know if there is negative weight cycle ,the Bellman ford algorithm needs to run  n times.
first n-1 times to calculate the shortest path and then one more time to check if there is any improvement in the distances if there are improvements ,it means there is a negative weight cycle.