# Bellman Ford Implementation and simultaneously relaxation

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph

Recently I see this question [Bellman Ford and Some Facts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520550/bellman-ford-and-one-olympiad-questions) as follows:

We know the bellman-ford algorithms check **all edges in each step**, and for each edge if, d(v)>d(u)+w(u,v) was hold then `d(v)` being updated. `w(u,v)` is the weight of edge `(u, v)` and `d(u)` is the length of best finding path for vertex `u`. if at any step there is `no update for any vertexes`, the algorithm `terminate`.

for finding all shortest path from vertex `s` in graph G with `n` vertexes this algorithm terminate after `k < n` iteration.

The following fact is true.

> number of edges in all shortest paths from `s` is at most `k-1`

in this [Book](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/book/08-sssp.pdf) we have 3 implementation (some optimization) of BFord. My question is that if we have
simultaneously relaxation which algorithm of these should be used, and by using it the above fact should be true? or not in general the above fact is true?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you have both java and c++ tags. We frown upon tag-spamming here.

Answer (score 0):

The final algorithm, `BellmanFordFinal(s)` is the optimised version of all the 3 mentioned algorithms.

**OPTIMIZATION 1:**

In the book, the legendary Prof. Jeff Erickson has explained, how the original algorithm presented by Bellman is optimised by removing the indentation of the last 3 lines in the algorithm.

Because the outermost iteration considers each edge `u->v` exactly once, the order in which they get processed, does not matter.

**OPTIMIZATION 2:**

The indices `i-1` has been changed to `i` in the last 2 lines, which enables the algorithm to work more faster with correct computation of the values (shortest path).

**OPTIMIZATION 3:**

The 2 dimensional DP array is converted to 1 dimension as it was needless.

Therefore, use the final algorithm, titled, `BellmanFordFinal(s)`.

**The fact that we need to run the outermost loop for `N-1` times is always true and independent of any implementation, because, the longest shortest path from a source to destination will be `N-1` in case of the linear graph, where N is the number of the nodes in the graph.**

**Answer to your concern about `k-1`**

> number of edges in all shortest paths from s is at most k-1

The above statement is dependent on the implementation of your algorithm.

If you add a if condition to break the outermost loop when none of the edges are further relaxed, then this statement is false.

Otherwise it is true.

Have a look at the following implementation I found on https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bellman_ford.html:

```
void solve()
{
    vector<int> d (n, INF);
    d[v] = 0;
    for (;;)
    {
        bool any = false;

        for (int j=0; j<m; ++j)
            if (d[e[j].a] < INF)
                if (d[e[j].b] > d[e[j].a] + e[j].cost)
                {
                    d[e[j].b] = d[e[j].a] + e[j].cost;
                    any = true;
                }

        if (!any) break;
    }
    // display d, for example, on the screen
}
```

The variable `any` is used to check if their is any relaxation done in any of the iteration. If not done, break the loop.

Therefore, it might happen that the loop gets terminated before, for example, when k=2 and the number of edges in the longest shortest path is 3. Now, 3 <= 2-1, does not hold correct.

Comment: perfect. a--> b-->--c , for every node after the first iteration get values. in this case, the algorithm stops after k=2 iterations because the second iteration does not change anything. Number of edges in the longest shortest path is 3 and 3 <= 2-1 does not hold. so this claim is false !!!!!!!!

Comment: Kindly do accept the answer if it solves your doubt.

Comment: I provide counter example for fact number of edges in all shortest paths from s is at most k-1. please inspect it.

Comment: For, a->b->c, the number of edges is 2. Also, 2 is less than or equal to N-1 = 3-1 = 2.

Comment: what about 4 vertex?

Comment: a->b->c->d ,   shortest path from a->d is three hops, BF has made two iterations.

Comment: The algorithm states 1 to V-1, right, so V = 4, in this case, therefore V-1 = 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225583/discussion-between-deepak-tatyaji-ahire-and-m-k).

Comment: M K, I have added the answer for your concern.

Comment: Like answer but @DeepakTatyajiAhire is it possible to show us this version in any formal book of algorithms or valid references?

Comment: exactly what is the mentioned algorithm like your answer and my fact be true always with it? no custom modification I means.

Comment: With no custom modification, the fact is true if you follow the final  algorithm mentioned in the book

Comment: so with which one is false?

Comment: Depends on implementation. For the custom one, mentioned by me, it is false. But for the optimised algorithm from the book, it is true.

Comment: I have mentioned a link to CP Algorithms in my answer @DaviedZuhraph